# Using the clipboard API from a Google Apps Script Web Application

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, html5-clipboard-api

I have a simple Web-application (written in Google Apps Script using the HtmlService)
When a user clicks a button, it used to "paste" whatever text is on the clipboard to an input field. That worked fine until some Chrome-version (I guess it was version 83)

```
    $(".readclipboard").on('click',async function(){
      const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
      console.log("clipboard read!");
      $("#boeknummer").val(text);
     });
```

When I check the console after clicking the button, I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Disabled in this document by Feature Policy.
```

Some research got me to this page:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/feature-policy#using

However, I can't figure out how I can set a "HTTP header" on Google Apps Script HTMLService.
It also seems like I can't set an "allow" attribute on the iFrame... Anyone?

Comment: Try: `document.execCommand('copy');` make sure focus is on the item that you want to copy